# Is it possible to assign search priorities in Google for specific websites?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

Is it possible to prioritize Google search to show my favorite sites first? Basically I would like some sites, for example superuser.com, to display first in the search results instead of sixth, seventh or on subsequent pages.

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now, but haven't found much on the web.

The result should look like a "reordering" rather than a filter or exclusion.

Comment: At a minimum Google has a `site:` operator you can use in a search, for example `site:superuser.com windows`

Comment: Yes, but that applies a filter, where everything else doesn't show, I'm referring to something that can "tidy up" the results.